# Why SqlParametersCollection require "@" at the start of the parameter name everytime?

Tags: c#, .net

Well , title of the question is pretty much the question itself, so why is it that I need to write "@" every time in front of sql parameter name like that?

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", this.CustomerId);
```

I know that this is how parameters are declared using SQL , but shouldn't that be handled by the framework as it is always like that?

Comment: Its database specific

Comment: What do you mean by it is database specific?

Comment: @kuskmen that every database has its own way of specifying parameters. With SQL Server it's `@`, with Oracle it's `:`.

Comment: You *don't* need to and it *is* handled by the framework. Internally, T-SQL variable names must always start with a `@`, but `SqlCommand` will add them for you if they're missing. What `AddWithValue` also does, and what you [should not be relying on](http://web.archive.org/web/20160513173456/http://blogs.msmvps.com:80/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), is inferring the data type of the parameter.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes , but I am using `SqlParametersCollection` it is obvious that I will use SQL Server , right? Why not framework do that for me?

Comment: @kuskmen that's not what the title or question text says. If that's what you meant, `Can I specify a parameter name without '@'` would be better. Jeroen's comment suggests that you already can.

Comment: @JeroenMostert where this is done? Decompiling `SqlParameterCollection, SqlParameter and SqlCommand` classes gives me nothing :(

Comment: @kuskmen even if it is done, you *shouldn't* use this, unless you want to forget to use the correct parameter names in the query string and spend time wondering why you get errors

Comment: [ReferenceSource SqlParameter ParameterNameFixed](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlParameter.cs,e0b0ddfdcb0fca98,references)

Comment: @Steve Thanks! You can answer this question so I can accept it and prove me wrong. I don't know why Panagiotis is sending blog posts about type inference while the question is about parameter names...

Comment: @kuskmen: He didn't -- I did, and I only did so because `.AddWithValue` is a bad idea that deserves to be pointed out as such no matter the context it appears in. :-P

Comment: @JeroenMostert ah right , my mistake , yea I will read about that , thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that you use Microsoft SQL Server. MS SQL names its variables this way and therefore you need to call them this way, too.

Comment: Yes, this is the case , but what other SQL Server can I use with `SqlParameterCollection` to be something different than that? I mean I guess every parameters in every SQL server are declared the same , right?

Comment: Yes, thats right. But the @ is simply the way SQL server names its variables. You can also use it to declare a table (which is a variable then)

Comment: Turns out I was wrong and framework is handling them internally , check comment below my question.

Answer (score 1):

Variable names in MS SQL Server must begin with an at (@) sign. Check how to [declare variables in SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql) for more info.

Comment: This is true , however I was curious why I had to do it myself in .NET since it is always like that why not framework do it itself, turns out I was wrong and it DID handle them.